# Multiple Find/Replace queries over multiple files: replace one by one

Tags: batch, software-rec, find-and-replace

What I want is this (Software can run on Linux or Windows, both are available):

- Supply a list of files in which strings should be replaced (wildcards ideal, but not mandatory)
- Supply a list of search/replace combinations. (each word will be replaced by another word)
- Now I'd like it to walk me through all results found and allow me to check whether the found string should be replaced in the file or not.

Of course I googled this, but it was hard to come up with a good search query. Whatever I found did not match what I wanted.
Could be I'm using the wrong combinations of words or something, just thought I'd drop by here and check  if someone here has a good idea.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Emacs can do the heavy lifting though not in the format you specify directly (using lists). See (http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/find_replace_inter.html). You will need to write some elisp.

Answer (score 0):

File rename: 
You might try the application available at http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk

File contents:
PowerShell will give you a very powerful command line, allowing you to make the change to any set or subset of text file contents nigh-instantaneously, but the "walk me through" would be a big pain to set up for someone not already familiar with that command line.

AutoHotKey, on the other hand, would allow you to create your own custom tailored program/script. My recommended method would be to do a "for" loop that would parse each line of each text file searching for the contents, and adjust the contents. You would also be able to insert an "interrupt" dialog asking if you would like to proceed with the replacement, even going so far as to include an input element to ask what to replace it with if it doesn't adhere to the standard variables from the script.

Comment: I think I mistyped my question. I meant find/replace in files, not to find/replace the filenames themselves. Sorry if I caught the wrong idea. (I edited the question to clear things up)

Comment: Aha! So these files would be text files, then, with modifiable text contents?

Comment: Yes. Textfiles and they can be changed of course.

Comment: There are a few options available for you, then, but none of them are particularly quick and easy. The two that appear the most friendly are AutoHotKey, or PowerShell. I've updated my answer to include some basic descriptions.

Comment: Your comment gave me an idea. I think I have a neat way of solving this problem. I am going to test that and will get back here if it doesn't work. Or get back here with a wonderful solution :) Thanks in advance.

Comment: Very eager to hear back with your results. Take care!